# Object with a uniform circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, centripetal-force, angular-velocity

A classical example of an object attached to a string and revolving horizontally with a constant angular velocity. The object is not rotating around its axis. What happens if we cut the string? Some assumptions: No gravity. Thus, Will maintain the Height. No friction force or any other external force.

The object will take the tangential path from the point we release. But will it rotate around its axis as well? Will there be any change in pose or it will be the same?

Comment: Just a note on terminology - an object *rotates* around its own axis (the earth rotates once every 24 hours), but *revolves* around an external axis (the earth revolves around the sun every 365 days). A object tied to a string and revolving around a center point also rotates with the same period as the revolution (you can see the point the string is tied to completes a full loop every revolution). Without some floating anchor point, the object will both revolve and rotate.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention on the terminology. So, In this case, The object will both rotate(because it is revolving) and revolve as well? Would not it take a tangential path instead of revolving? I would like to read more about it if you could recommend me some material. Thank you

Comment: When released, the object will take a tangential path and no longer revolve around the central point. It will continue to rotate around its own axis at the same rate as before - a ball with its string will still continue to rotate slowly as it flies off in a straight line. You can imagine if the gravitational "string" connecting the earth and the sun were cut, the earth would no longer revolve around the sun as it flew off into space, but the day length (rotation) would still be 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

> The object is not rotating around its axis.

Even though the [instant center of rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation) lies outside the object, that doesn't mean that it's not "rotating about its own axis".  The rotational period is identical when measured from any inertial (non-rotating) reference frame.

In the same way, we say the earth rotates on its axis even though it has other complex motions (depending on the reference frame).

In all these non-rotating frames, we will see the rotational period of the object remains the same before and after the string is cut.

Comment: Thank you. So If I observe from a Non-rotating inertial reference frame , After I cut the string, The object will go on a circular path with same RPM?   Will it not follow a tangential path after I cut the string?

Comment: I said nothing about the path.  Only the orientation/rotation of the object.  You already described the path it takes in the question and didn't appear to ask anything about it, so it's not addressed.

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose an spherical object and focus in an volume element close to the string, its distance to the rotation center is $R-r$, where $R$ is the distance from the rotation center to the center of mass, and $r$ is the distance from the element to the center of mass.

For an element at the opposite side of sphere, its distance is $R+r$.

When the string is cut, each element has a different momentum: $p_i = dm\omega (R-r)$ and $p_o = dm\omega (R+r)$. And the momentum of an element in the CM is $p_{cm} = dm\omega R$.

For the object follows a trajectory without rotating, both momentum at the periphery should be changed, to match the momentum of CM, and that would require a force.

As there is not such a force, the object keeps rotating as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

When the string is cut there is now no external force acting on the object therefore the object will continue in a straight line that is tangent to the circle at the point where the force stopped acting.

Answer (score 0):

Blue5000 and BowlOfRed are both correct.
Blue notes the conservation of linear momentum, or Newton's 1st Law. It look's like you're good with that based on your conversation with Red.
Red focuses on a topic that's a little less intuitive (at least for me). I want to expound on their answer with a familiar example: The Moon's orbit around Earth. The same side of the Moon always faces Earth. As a result, it's tempting to say that the Moon is not rotating. However, the Moon is rotating with an period equal to its orbital period around Earth. This is a consequence of tidal locking, and it is the equivalent of the string attached to the object in your scenario.
That should mean that the object in your scenario is rotating about its axis with an angular speed equal to that of its CM around the center of the string.

My guess is that, when the string is cut, the object will travel with a constant linear velocity (as noted) and continue to rotate around its CM with that same angular speed.

Illustration to help visualize the Moon's rotation.

[image]

Image comes from http://ipfactly.com/you-always-see-the-same-side-of-the-moon/

Wikipedia's [article on Tidal locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking).